# how to understand "ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]" rails / ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

- `ActiveRecord` is a Class
- `ActiveRecord::Migration` is a module
- `[5.2]` is array with one `Float`

But what means `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby allows you to define a `[]` method like this:

```
  class Foo
    def [](bar)
      puts bar
    end
  end
```

Then you can do:

```
x = Foo.new
foo["baz"] # prints baz
```

This also works with a class method `[]`, not just with an instance one:

```
class Foo
  def self.[](bar)
    puts bar
  end
end
```

Now `Foo["a"]` prints a.

Rails is taking advantage of this through this code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L543

So the `[5.2]` in your example is not an array with a float inside, it's a call to the `ActiveRecord::Migration.[]` method with 5.2 as the argument.

Comment: I know ruby allow define [] but I don't think about self.[] :) but it's logic ! ;) thx