# Rails migrations - what to do with old migrations after you upgrade Rails version? e.g. ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2] => 6,1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a legacy Rails app that's in production for a few years.
It started as Rails 5.2 app and has been recently upgraded to Rails6+.

```
ag ActiveRecord db/migrate | grep Migration
db/migrate/20181012164950_add_foos.rb:3: class AddFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
db/migrate/20201008043949_add_bars.rb:3: class AddBars < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
```

I'm wondering what's the recommended way of handling db migrations generated in an older Rails version(notice `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]` parent class name) after you upgraded your Rails dependency?

Is it recommended to update those numbers(e.g. [5.2] to your latest version instead(to future proof it)? Is it safe at all?

Related questions:

[What are the brackets [5.1] after ActiveRecord Migration and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126483/what-are-the-brackets-5-1-after-activerecord-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

[how to understand "ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]" rails / ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541125/how-to-understand-activerecordmigration5-2-rails-ruby)

Comment: I'd delete them. Your `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql` has everything already and the chances of successfully rolling back that far are pretty much zero. Old migrations are just in the way.